# why we are using 1 = 1 in SQL select Query

Tags: sql, coldfusion

Can anyone please explain Why we are using `where 1=1` in SQL select query?

```
Select * from <TableName>
Where 1=1
<cfif isdefined('Something)>
AND  columnName = value
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tools often use this to let them append AND some_other_condition to the query, without having to worry whether this is the first predicate or not.

If you write

```
SELECT * FROM A
```

...and want to add a predicate you need to append "WHERE C1=1", but then adding a second predicate would append "AND C2=1"

But if you write

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE 1=1
```

...you can just append "AND C1=1" for the first, and "AND C2=1" for the second

Comment: my vote just put your reputation over 2000.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: much appreciated.

Comment: @mc110 Thank u! got my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen and used 'Where 1 = 0' to just create a new table with the same schema but without any data. But this one escapes me. The where clause is just not required here and the query would give the same result with or without the where clause.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer. You need to wait until you have 50 reputation to comment on posts other than your own.

Comment: I am a new here and it does not help that you people keep bringing me down to zero !!

Comment: If you post comments as answers, they will be downvoted and eventually deleted. You need to post actual answers until you have enough reputation to post comments; before that you just can't comment.

Comment: I vote it up, his answer helps me know other aspect as well about 1 = 0

Comment: I'm voting it up because I'm a bad Stack Overflower.  The other use of where 1 = 0 is that it enables you to follow it with "or this = that" conditions.

Comment: *the query would give the same result with or without the where clause* Not quite. Due to the `cfif`, the actual sql generated depends on whether or not the `something` variable exists. If it does exist, the sql becomes `..WHERE 1 = 1 AND columnName = value`, which is not the same as `...WHERE 1 = 1`.

Comment: @DanBracuk Thank you for explaining the use of 1 = 0 too

Comment: @anonxen Thank u too for making a start on the concept of 1 = 0.